# AngularJS error: Name "IServiceProvider" cannot be found

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm building an app with the ionic framework. I use Visual Studio 2015 for it. When I run my App with ripple, everything works fine. But then I had a bluescreen and now it didnt work anymore. I dont know if that is related to the bluescreen. When I start ripple now, I get this messages:

> Non-whitespace before first tag. in C:...\MyApp\MDAVSCLI 1
>
> Name "IServiceProvider" can not be found. in
>   C:...\MyApp\www\lib\angular-ui-router\api\angular-ui-router.d.ts 31
>
> Name "IServiceProvider" can not be found. in
>   C:...\MyApp\www\lib\angular-ui-router\api\angular-ui-router.d.ts 49
>
> Name "IPromise" can not be found. in
>   C:...\MyApp\www\lib\angular-ui-router\api\angular-ui-router.d.ts 82

I translated the errors, so it could be a bit different in english. Someone know how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to remove TypeScript file, angular-ui-router.d.ts - [see](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-ionic/#typescript)

Answer (score 1):

It is happens due to this file that may be created automatically, when you run your project for the first time after modification: **angular-ui-router.d.ts**

Search it and Delete it from the path:

Good Luck !

Comment: Please don't create duplicate answers, instead upvote the existing one giving the exact same advise

Comment: i did/do not create duplicate answers, but i shared my newest experience !

Comment: Then have a look at the answer of Jan Bouchner just above yours

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by remove platform and add again

ionic platform rm android (remove)

ionic platform add android (add)

Comment: I tried to start my App now with the google android emulator and now the last 3 errors came again. Maybe someone know ho to fix it?

Comment: Hi, did you resolved it? I have exactly the same problem.